# How can I change the fonts in android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, fonts, textview

I am try change the font, but not working. Are returning "null" being that I set the value in the XML and also in the code.

Kotlin Code

```
 val typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(tvThanks.context.assets, "dinpro_medium.ttf")
        tvThanks.setTypeface(typeFace)
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvThanks"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text_here"/>
```

ERROR

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: tvThanks must not be null
    at br.com.adrianofpinheiro.testesantander.fragment.ContatoEnviadoFragment.onCreate(ContatoEnviadoFragment.kt:21)
```

Comment: Where are you defining `tvThanks` in your Kotlin code?

Comment: Views inside fragment do not exist during `onCreate`. Move your code to `onViewCreated`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fragment should have the `context` property without getting from the `tvThanks`.

I think you can try doing this inside the `onCreateView` of your fragment

```kotlin
 val typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "dinpro_medium.ttf")
        tvThanks!!.setTypeface(typeFace)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Photos : Fragment() {
private lateinit var rootView: View
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.skeleton_photos_tab, container, false)
    return rootView
}
```

}

now you can do this.

```
rootView.tvThanks.setTypeface(typeFace)
```